# Is it possible to reference/embed an xib file into a XamarinForms view and inherit from a custom view controller?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

We're using a third party SDK that defines its own views(Around 15 xib's) and uses the outlets set on the views to perform some actions. This logic resides in their SDK, driven by their CustomViewController and delegates. We use it pretty much out of the box without having to customize it further.

Is there a way to embed the entire xib into a ContentPage directly, without having to build out the views in xaml? Ideally, we'd like to embed the xibs, and use the SDK's CustomViewController as is. Maybe in a PageRenderer, which is a problem in itself because the PageRenderer is just a wrapper around a UIViewController, but we need to inherit from the CustomViewController.

While we understand that it's possible to embed native UI elements into a Forms view, what we want is to be able to embed the whole xib, and also inherit from a custom VC. Any insight into how these two problems can be tackled?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have those options, none of them is exactly what you ask and you'll have to find what works the best for you:

- building a custom native view with a custom renderer
- using the native pages and loading Xamarin ContentPages there as ViewControllers and mixing as you wish with your xibs

Eventually you may also try to access the root UIView and inject your subview there, but it is likely to interfere with Xamarin layout and likely to lead to problems, so do it on your own risk.